# Particle system playing once on gui button?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i success to play particle system with gui button, but i found new problem, when my particle system (Pa is my particle system 1) play , and i try to press gui button again Pa will play again, i want when i press gui button, The Pa play, but when i press it again the pa is not play. how to do that? this is my script.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Play : MonoBehaviour {
public ParticleSystem Pa;
public ParticleSystem Pa2;
void OnGUI(){
    if(GUI.Button(new Rect(8*Screen.width/10 ,Screen.height/10, Screen.width/10,Screen.height/10),"Play")){
        Pa.Play();
        Pa2.Play();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Store a boolean to administrate whether or not the particle system has already played?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that OnGUI call every frame, so your if-statemenet is being called every frame to check whether the button is pressed or not.

Now, as Bart commented, you should just store a boolean var, to check whether the particle has played or not, or you can use the isPlaying var that is implemented inside the particle system.

So your code should look like:

```
void OnGUI(){
if(GUI.Button(new Rect(8*Screen.width/10 ,Screen.height/10, Screen.width/10,Screen.height/10),"Play")){
    if(!Pa.isPlaying)
       Pa.Play();
    else
       Pa.Stop();
    if(!Pa2.isPlaying)
       Pa2.Play();
    else
       Pa2.Stop();
  }
}
```

For more reference about how to use the Particle System, you can check here:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.html

Comment: _thank  you for answer my problem, your code worked well, but when i press gui button , the Pa  stopped , so it make the Pa2 not play. I think when i pressed gui button , the Pa must not active, can you help me again?_

Comment: Look at the code again, I didn't understand what you wanted to accomplish.

Comment: _the code works well, FYI I set Pa's duration 15 seconds, Pa2 has delay 15 seconds and duration 5 seconds, if i implement your code, first i pressed the gui button, so the Pa will play,  and i tried to press gui button again, the Pa isn't playing again, i think the problem solved... but It means if i pressed gui button for second time, it effects Pa will stop, and Pa2 will not playing after Pa.

i want gui button if i press for second, three, four times, it doesn't effects for my particle system (Pa and pa2_)